# can anyone help me find why my hero image is not working in css?

Tags: html, css, header

[image]I am a beginner trying to do a school project every time after watching tutorial I still couldn't able to figure out why my image is not working in css. Hereby attaching my code for both Html and Css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Responsive website</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reset-css@3.0.0/reset.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Assets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="brand-title">Brand Name</div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-links">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="hero">
    </div>
 </header>
      <script src="/Assets/main.js" defer></script>
</body>
```

```
header {
height: 100%;
    color: red;
    background: url('../img/hero.jpg');
}

.hero {
    position:left;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-40%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Hello Spectric I have added both Html and css

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?" What is the expected result?

Comment: I couldn't able to see the image on my website.

Comment: Are you sure the image path ("`'../img/hero.jpg`") is correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct!

Comment: Try clearing your cache.

Comment: did that too still not working

Comment: Can you post your file structure? We really can't help with the information you provided.

Comment: I have an Assets folder which contains my main.js and style.css and img folder which has my image and an index.html

Comment: Please edit you question with a picture of your files structure.

Comment: I have added the picture, sorry I am so confused as I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a tab to your `height` attribute where your header selector is at.

Comment: If that doesn't work get rid of the "/Assets" from your href attribute in your head tag, because if all of your files are inside of your Assets folder, you don't have to reference the Assets folder. just put href="styles.css".@Vasanth Maran

Comment: Also get rid of the "../" from your background selector where you have url('../hero.jpg') because you don't have to go back a directory in order to get to your img folder. @Vasanth Maran

Comment: If I am removing /Assets in href attribute my css is not working completely

Comment: @Adam Breslin I removed .. from the /hero.jpg still not working but when I put the image inside the body tag in css like background-image: url('/img/hero.jpg'); it works but I don't know how to adjust the height, width and position of that

Comment: @Spectric I created the same file structure that Vasanth Maran is using and when I get rid of the /Assets it works perfectly. I'm using Visual Studio Code like he is too. I also got rid of the ../ from the beginning of the url in his css and the image appeared for me, so I don't know what the problem is. If all of his files are in his Assets Folder, he doesn't need to reference the "../"

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check your css if it is working properly for example set the background of your body to red and check your image if it is in jpg or jpeg format.

Comment: this is how I am viewing the background colour

Comment: try using other image if it is working maybe the image your using is corrupt

Comment: I replicated everything and it works fine. maybe try opening the folder again. Click file > Open Folder > then select this folder Responsivecssgrid_flexbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use vh (viewport height) instead of percent to achieve this – learn more about viewport units here: [Fun with Viewport Units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)

> Viewport Height (vh) – A percentage of the full viewport height. 10vh will resolve to 10% of the current viewport height.

Try changing your header CSS:

```
header {
  height: 75vh; /* 100vh would be the full height of the viewport */
  color: red;
  background: url('../img/hero.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Responsive website</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reset-css@3.0.0/reset.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Assets/style.css" />

    <style>
      header {
        color: red;
        background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80);
        background-position: center;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .navbar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }

      .navbar-links ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }

      .navbar-links ul li {
        margin-right: 2rem;
        list-style: none;
        margin-top:2rem;
        
      }

      .navbar-links ul li a {
       text-decoration: none;
       font-size: 20px;
       color: #fff;
       background-color:rgb(93, 84, 84);
       padding:10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="brand-title">Brand Name</div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-links">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="hero"></div>
    </header>
    <script src="/Assets/main.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```